# How to inject EmtityManager to BaseDao in wildfly8?

Tags: java, jpa, cdi, wildfly

In my BaseDao , I use

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary") 
protected EntityManager em;
```

to inject an EntityManager and other daos inherit from it , for example ,UserDao. In my project,I use

```
@Inject
private UserDao userDao;
```

sometimes, not everytime, it throws exception like 
Can not set javax.persistence.EntityManager field com.XXX.storage.dao.BaseDao.em to com.XXX.storage.dao.UserDao$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass ,I dont know the reason ,can anyone help me?Many thanks!

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the internal structure of your application. Are your daos packaged in a jar file that is shared between modules (ejb and or web)? And if so, do the errors occur when the daos are used from different modules? If both of these are true then the mapping of your entity manager must be wrong in some of the modules.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes ,my daos are packaged in a jar file that is shared between modules (not ejb) and these daos are used from different modules. what should i do to resolve this problem? I am a newbie.

Comment: In short you need to make sure that all references to external resources are resolved properly from all modules. Without seeing your whole code base and all error messages it is hard to give specific instructions, but, look through your logs and find if there are any errors related to datasource mappings or similar resources. It is possible that the JPA configuration is accessible from one module but not the other. Or that the datasource mapping is different between the modules. If you can workout which module is working, make all the others the same as that.